# Error al retornar a ruta Post - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buen día a todos, estoy trabajando el laravel 5.6, tengo un inconveniente, tengo una ruta `post` que trabaja con el formulario `Register.blede.php` , este formularia envía sus datos del `form` mediante la `Request` a otra ruta `post`, en esta ultima ruta busca la `function store` en el `ClienteController@store`, en ella esta el método de validación de la `request()->validate` y toda la validación necesaria, el detalle surge cuando una de las validaciones no coincide y retorna a la ruta del formulario, pues me retorna a la misma dirección de la ruta pero en get.

La vista: index.blade.php

```
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-12">
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'confirmar.store', 'method' => 'POST','autocomplete'=>'off']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" id="apellido">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sexo">Sexo</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="sexo" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option>Mujer</option>
        <option>Hombre</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edad">Edad</label>
        <input type="number" name="edad" class="form-control" id="edad" placeholder="name@example.com">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="detalle">Detalles</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="detalle" name="detalle" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registra</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

las rutas:

```
Route::post('confirmar-datos/datos-cliente', array(
  'as' => 'confirmar_datos.index',
  'uses' => 'ClienteController@index'
));

Route::post('/confirmar-datos/store', array(
      'as' => 'confirmar.store',
      'uses' => 'ClienteController@store'
));
```

function insert (controller)

```
public function store(Request $request ){

        request()->validate([
            'email'=> 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'sexo' => 'required',
            'edad'=> 'numeric',
            'nombre'=> 'required|max:50',
             'apellidos'=> 'required|max:70',

        ]);
        return ("validacion correcta");
    }
```

si no cumple las reglas de validación me sale el error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

busca una ruta get lugar de post.

PD: quisas debo de cambiar la primera ruta a get, pero en esa también realizo inserción de datos llevándome al este formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes que acceder a una ruta por post y get usa match, así puedes poner todos los verbos que necesites. Si necesitas que permita todos, puedes usar ::any

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
    //
});
```